# How to enable root account Ubuntu 14.0.4 permanent

Tags: root

I am working under ubuntu 14.0.4. I have an application which I did in c++. This computer in which I am working is going to be use only for execute this applications, nothing else, no internet, no personal computer, only for run this applications.

The thing is that I need to enable the root account in this computer I undestand the risk, but it is going only to run this application. So what I want to do is whenever I boot the computer start automatic root user always. How can I do that?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know a way to automatically login using root but heres a way to login to root account from the greeter(Unity login screen).
In the terminal type

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Then add the line

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

And then restart and login by typing "root" as username and type in the root password.
Login using root is risky especially on an internet connected machine.(Don't promise your money thinking Linux is virus-free.)

Comment: I assume you know how to enable root using "sudo passswd".

Comment: commenting your own answer isn't a good way to get in touch the OP.

Comment: Hi Rohan many thanks for your quick answer, I did that, but I want that the root account log in automatic, and also I want that this account would be de "default" account, how can I do this??